# Inverse function for moveTaskToBack

Tags: java, android

Is where any function which returns Activities to foreground from Service?
I can move activities to background by `moveTaskToBack(true);`
How to return all activities back?

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(service.getBaseContext(), class_);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
        service.getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

The code below just adds Acitivies to history and do not open them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is called [moveTaskToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#moveTaskToFront%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: I think you helped me.  Thanks